# Trying to extend inner div height past container div height

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create an effect where the blue section extends past the gray section.

The blue section is currently contained within the gray section, which may be the problem.

http://nufios.com/node

I've got this as the HTML:

```
<div id="header-wrapper">

  <div id="header">

...

</div></div>
```

And this as the CSS:

```
#header-wrapper {
width: 100%;
background-color: #686868;
}

#header {
width: 60%;
background-color: #45719E;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0 2em 2em 2em;
position: relative;
}
```

How do I get it so that the blue section is centered within the gray section, and can still go down below the gray section (i.e., the height is greater on the blue section).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using z-index and fixed heights:

CSS:

```
#header-wrapper {
width: 100%;
background-color: #686868;
height:30px;
}

#header {
width: 60%;
background-color: #45719E;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0 2em 2em 2em;
position: relative;
z-index:10;
height:50px;
}
```

jFiddle demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/LynchJustRules/RQV4h/

Answer (score 0):

Just give your *#header-wrapper* `height`. If you want to always fit the blue box's height when its height is less than the gray box's, set the `max-height`

```
#header-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #686868;
  max-height: 92px;
}
```

Comment: The blue box will be bigger than the gray box(in height), always.